# Restore Default Gnome Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and added the classic gnome so it would look like ubuntu 10.04 ( I liked that classic look better).

Today I accidentally deleted everything from the panel. Since I am quite new to Ubuntu I now can't get it back as it was.

Can anyone tell me how to get it back to look like as it was before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Reset GNOME Classic and  gnome-panel configuration on 12.04 Type following commands in terminal.

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-panel/

killall gnome-panel
```

Comment: It shows me error $ dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-panel/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dconf", line 481, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/dconf", line 336, in main
    symlink(which('dconf'), cronfile)
  File "/usr/bin/dconf", line 216, in symlink
    os.symlink(src, dst)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: I solved the problem my self! But thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

**If you want** to add things to the panel in gnome-classic environment you have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super=Windows key</kbd> + right click on the panel.